# Name Error python, a text adventure game

Tags: python-3.x, adventure

So i have a problem, that i don't quite understand why it's happening. I get a (Name Error global variable "value" is not defined) when it should be on my weapons class.

```
from items import *

class weapons(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, attack_damage, lifesteal = 0):
        super(weapons,self).__init__(name, value, quantity=1)
        self.attack_damage = attack_damage
        self.lifesteal = lifesteal
```

Here is the class that weapons is getting it from that already has value defined.

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, quantity=1):
        self.name = name
        self.raw = name.replace(" ","").lower()
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.value = value
        self.netValue = quantity * value
    def recalc(self):
        self.netValue = self.quantity * self.value
```

I already have a piece of code similar to this that is working, but for some reason this value error is happening. I'm just going to include it.

```
from character import*
class player(character):
    def __init__(self,name,hp,maxhp,attack_damage,ability_power):
        super(player,self).__init__(name, hp, maxhp)
        self.attack_damage = attack_damage
        self.ability_power = ability_power
```

and the class that player is getting its stuff from

```
class character(object):
    def __init__(self,name,hp,maxhp):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxhp = maxhp
    def attack(self,other):
        pass
```

as you can see i did it here and this piece of code works when i call a player.

Comment: Where do you think `value` is coming from in your line `super(weapons,self).__init__(name, value, quantity=1)`? Should `value` be `attack_damage`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `value` argument to the `__init__` constructor of the weapons class.

Comment: +1 for identifying that `value` was "almost defined" - I was doing this on my phone and didn't see that.

Comment: @Floris I think my answer is wrong; where is self.value defined?

Comment: In the class `Item`? "Here is the class that weapons is getting it from".

Comment: @Floris Yes, but the `value` attribute will only be set in the `Item` instance, right?

Comment: I did the self.value but now it says i have an attribute error: "weapon" object has no attribute "value"

Answer (score 0):

`super` needs a parameter `value` but you did not pass it into the **init**